# Upload box media size not working

Tags: images, media

I recently downloaded wordpress 3.5.1 and installed it on my website.
This should be the website that is launched in the air.

On the demo site when i click on Add Media and want to change the image to thumbnail / medium / large / full screen it works.

Now in the version i launched in the air i can only select full screen and not thumbnail / medium or large.

I only changed my thumbnail at the options-media page for 150 x 150, large to 500 x 398.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late, but I'm having the same problem and looking for a solution. [This other question seems to describe the same problem](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/138880/media-sizes-arent-being-created-server-config), and the solution is that maybe the needed image libraries (GD or ImageMagick) are not included by the server configuration. That was the case for me.

I hope this helps someone. ^^