# Media sizes aren't being created - server config?

Tags: images, media, apache

I have 3 sites with WordPress on a RedHat Centos server. Everything were fine until days ago, when I needed to recompile Apache to use mb_string, so I did it using WHM "Easy Apache".

But from then, my sites aren't creating image sizes. I mean, when I upload an image, aditional sizes (already defined on functions) aren't created. If I look inside media folders, only the original file is there, and none thumbnail or extra sizes. When I try to insert media inside posts, no aditional sizes appears on menu.

Any idea on what happened? Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It looks like "Easy Apache" handles both Apache and PHP](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/EasyApache/WebHome). Only a guess, but you have recompiled Apache/PHP without the needed image libraries-- either `GD` or `ImageMagick`. Without those, the server cannot physically resize images.

You can use a `phpinfo()` script to see if the libraries are present. If not, you will need to recompile-- or whatever that "Easy Apache" system allows-- and make sure the needed libraries are included. Maybe you can add modules one by one using that system. Not sure.

Comment: I'll check it, but it's strange, since I did the rebuild using previous configs + mbstring. But maybe you're right.

Comment: You were right, for some reason GD was disabled. Thank you!